# Azure Service Fabric - Auto generate PowerShell script to recreate

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

Once we have our Azure Service Fabric cluster setup the way we want, I'd like to create a PowerShell script that can recreate it in an emergency. Is there a way via the Portal, or by some other means, we can have a PowerShell script automatically created that will recreate our Fabric setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Automate" button in the resource group. It will download a zip files with the ARM template and a script to deploy that template.

Comment: how can we do this with on premise SF?

Comment: In Azure the resource groups contains not only the cluster and it's configuration, but all the infrastructure as well. For on-prem scenarios, there is the cluster configuration file which you need. You can retrieve it using the Get-ClusterConfiguration cmdlet - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/get-servicefabricclusterconfiguration?view=azureservicefabricps

Comment: oh i see, i thought that the question was also asking basically how to roll back to the snapshot of when the services were functioning - sorry misunderstoodo, thank you again